# Box Authentication for v2?

Tags: ios, box-api

To Authenticate the app , simple way is I get a ticket by this method "GET https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_ticket&api_key=" and finally " https://m.box.com/api/1.0/auth/ " the url open up the login page in safari, it was easy in v1 iOS SDK.Now I could not able to authenticate after entering credentials and clicking login I cannot enter into my application. I have been facing authentication issue. How to authenticate using new iOS SDK v2 ?

Answer (score 0):

What error u getting?

Also Try using POSTMAN Google chrome extension to do the authentication as a command line and try to implement on your real app, u will find supportive docs on Box website. Make sure all your parameters are correctly entered.

Comment: i could not authenticate successfully cleanly I have messed up with method.I tried sample application provided by BOX and web view opens and say uri mismatch. But I have entered correctly all backend parameters.

Comment: Try doing everything first through commandline using POSTMAN or cURL